# Python Numpy array indexing and masking

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**I need help indexing a 3 dimensional array (an RGB/BGR image) using a 2 dimensional array of indices.** All values are either 0, 1, or 2 for different color channels. The result should be a 2D array of color values. If anyone can tell me the syntax for this in python that would be great!

For a context of what I am trying to do (also read TLDR below):

I am essentially trying to convert the following code from normal for loop syntax which is very very slow to a more efficient python/numpy syntax:

```
colorIndices = np.zeros((height,width));       # an array which has the index of the outstanding color
colorIndices -= 1;           # all -1's

for x in range(0,width):
    for y in range(0,height):

        pix = img[y,x];        # get the pixel, a 1D array of length 3
        colorID = np.argmax(pix);           #get which index has max value (candidate for outstanding color)

        if(pix[colorID]>np.average(pix)+np.std(pix)):      # if that value is more than one std dev away from the overall pixel's value, the pixel has an outstanding color
            colorIndices[y,x] = colorID;
```

I then would like to access the outstanding color channels in each pixel using something like:

```
img[:,:,:]=0;
img[colorIndices] = 255;
```

TLDR: **I want to set a pixel to pure blue, green, or red if it is a shade of that color. The way I define if a pixel is shade red is if the R value of the pixel is more than one std above the average of the overall distribution of {R, G, B}.**

The broken code I have so far:

```
  colorIDs = np.argmax(img, axis=2);

  averages = np.average(img, axis=2);
  stds = np.std(img, axis=2);
  cutoffs = averages + stds;

  print(img[colorIDs]);
```

[image: Here is an example of the image I am using]

Comment: Can you paste a sample of `img`

Comment: Why/ how is your code broken and what is the shape of img?

Comment: @MadPhysicist My code is just not complete and I have no idea how to finish it to satisfy my goal. I should've said not complete.

Comment: @najeem The image is suppose to be generic to any size, but I will upload the one I am using for your convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a numerical index along a given axis into values, you can use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) or [fancy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). When using a fancy index, you need to index along all axes with arrays whose shapes broadcast to the size of the final result. [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) helps with this. For an MxNx3 array `img` (`M, N, _ = img.shape`), if you had `ix = np.argmax(img, axis=2)`, the index would look like this:

```
r, c = np.ogrid[:M, :N]
maxes = img[r, c, ix]
```

Using `take_along_axis` saves you a step and some temp arrays:

```
maxes = np.take_along_axis(img, ix, 2)
```

Now create your mask:

```
significant = np.abs(maxes - img.mean(axis=2) > img.std(axis=2))
```

At this point you have a 2D boolean mask and an integer index in the third dimension. The simplest thing is probably to turn everything into a linear index:

```
r, c = np.where(significant)
```

Now you can construct the output:

```
color_index = np.zeros_like(img)
color_index[r, c, ix[significant]] = 255
```

While tempting, [`np.put_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html) can not be used here in a straightforward manner. The issue is that masking `ix` with `significant` would invalidated its shape similarity. You could, however, create an intermediate 2D array containing 255 at the locations marked by `significant`, and use that with `put_along_axis`:

```
values = np.zeros(significant.shape, dtype=img.dtype)
values[significant] = 255
color_index = np.zeros_like(img)
np.put_along_axis(color_index, ix, values, 2)
```

All combined:

```
ix = np.argmax(img, axis=2)
significant = np.abs(np.take_along_axis(img, ix, 2) - img.mean(axis=2)) > img.std(axis=2)
color_index = np.zeros_like(img)
color_index[(*np.where(significant), ix[significant])] = 255
```

Comment: what are the M and N variables?

Comment: And also, those asterisks in that last block of code do not run for me and it says syntax error.

Comment: M and N are height and width. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 3.7

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems that color_index will be a 2D grayscale image. Is this true? I would prefer if it were a colored image that held the pure color if it were an outstanding pixel, and the exact pixel color other wise.

Comment: You're right. I've probably fixed both issues not, but can't really test since I'm on a mobile platform. I'll update you once I've had a chance to play with this on a desktop in a couple of hours.

Comment: @akarshkumar0101. I've fixed all the code snippets by actually testing them.

Comment: @akarshkumar0101. I've shown how to use take/put_along_axis here. take definitely makes sense, but you won't get any mileage out of put.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to apply the 2d indexing mask from `argmax` to the 2nd axis:

```
In [38]: img=np.random.randint(0,10,(16,16,3))
In [39]: ids = np.argmax(img, axis=2)
In [40]: ids
Out[40]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1],
       [2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
In [41]: I,J = np.ix_(np.arange(16), np.arange(16))
In [42]: img[I,J,ids]
Out[42]: 
array([[5, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 5, 7, 1, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 6, 8],
       [6, 7, 5, 8, 5, 6, 9, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 3, 7, 9, 5],
       [7, 6, 8, 7, 6, 9, 6, 8, 9, 5, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 6],
       [8, 9, 3, 4, 7, 5, 8, 4, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9, 9, 9, 7],
       [9, 8, 9, 7, 9, 8, 7, 5, 8, 9, 9, 6, 9, 5, 8, 8],
       [7, 9, 8, 8, 9, 3, 6, 9, 8, 6, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 5, 8, 9, 8, 8, 2, 8, 7, 8, 9, 5, 5, 6, 7],
       [9, 6, 6, 9, 5, 3, 6, 4, 7, 6, 8, 8, 6, 3, 9, 9],
       [7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 7, 5, 9, 6, 4, 7, 7, 8, 5, 7, 8],
       [9, 7, 6, 4, 8, 9, 3, 8, 9, 2, 6, 9, 6, 7, 9, 7],
       [9, 8, 6, 6, 5, 9, 3, 9, 2, 4, 9, 5, 9, 9, 6, 9],
       [8, 7, 8, 3, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 5, 9, 8, 6, 9, 7, 8],
       [8, 2, 7, 7, 4, 5, 9, 8, 8, 8, 6, 5, 3, 9, 9, 6],
       [6, 8, 8, 5, 8, 8, 8, 9, 3, 7, 7, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9],
       [3, 7, 9, 9, 8, 5, 9, 8, 9, 7, 3, 3, 9, 5, 5, 9],
       [8, 4, 3, 6, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 7, 5, 8]])
```

Recent numpy versions have a function that does this for us

```
np.take_along_axis(img, ids[:,:,None], 2)[:,:,0]
```

and to set values `np.put_along_axis`.

Comment: Does this create the mask of 0's and 255's though?

Comment: @MadPhysicist the take along axis method was what I was looking for(indexing with a 2D array), but I couldn’t apply it to what I was doing afterwords. Your post solved that.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for tipping me off about take_along_axis. I'd been utterly and blissfully unaware of that function. Unfortunately, I don't think put_along_axis works as advantageously as take in OP's case.